# How to change the ObjectContext class name of edmx

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, edmx

The modes and classes are generated by Entity Framework 5 when I updated the mode from exist database . But I want to correct the name of the ObjectContext class. I know we can use the refactor tools of visual studio 2010, But I am not sure all the code files can be updated in this way. please help me .thanks.

Comment: If you want to change the generated class names in a way that the changes are not overwritten you have to modify the t4 template (the .tt file).

Comment: If you are using Model first pattern with EF, there is not t4 template. t4 template is only for code first . thanks.

Comment: You can add a code generation item.